# Issue With Nested If Statement

Tags: c, if-statement

I was trying to ask the user if he/she wants another cupcake only if the cost of the first cupcake is less than their budget (maxPrice), but that does not work. It prints nothing after receiving user input. The error occurs where the program states: "if(anotherCupcake == "yes")" and it also occurs when it states, "anotherCupcake == "no".
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    float maxPrice;
    char flavor[20];
    char flavor2[20];
    float price;
    double price2;
    char anotherCupcake[20];
    double newPrice;


   // int idxToDel = 2;
    //memove(&word[idxToDel], &word[idxToDel + 1], strlen(word) - idxToDel);

    printf("Please enter starting budget: ");
    scanf("%f", &maxPrice);
    printf("Enter the flavor of cupcake 1: ");
    scanf("%s", &flavor);
    printf("Enter the price of %s cupcake: $", flavor);
    scanf("%f", &price);

    //determining if you have enough money for a second cupcake
    if(price == maxPrice)
    {
        printf("\nOops! No more money left to spend on anymore cupcakes...enjoy the %s one! Bye!", flavor);
    }
    else if(price > maxPrice)
    {

        newPrice=maxPrice-price;
        printf("\nWow, you overspent on that first cupcake...you owe $%.2lf. Bye!", fabs(newPrice)*1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Ok, looks like you you have $%.2f left to spend on cupcakes...  Would you like to get another one?", maxPrice - price);
        scanf("%s", &anotherCupcake);

        //figuring out what second cupcake you want
        if(anotherCupcake == "yes")
        {
           printf("Enter the flavor of cupcake 2: ");
           scanf("%s", &flavor2);
           printf("Enter the price of cupcake 2 $: ");
           scanf("%f", &price2);
           printf("Done! Enjoy your %s and %s cupcakes! Bye!", flavor, flavor2);

        }
        if(anotherCupcake == "no")
        {
            printf("Ok then...Enjoy that one %s cupcake! Bye!", flavor);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not bear on your reported problem but `if(price == maxPrice)` will be a problem. Checking for exact equality with floats doesn't work well on a computer due to the inexact precision of floating point representation. Why not used integers and treat them as fixed point? Then you can do exact checks.

Comment: Your code also generates numerous warnings when compiled. You should examine those and resolve.

Comment: I tried your code and I get output after providing input. Please be more specific on what works and what doesn't.

Comment: When inputting a string leave off the `&`: `scanf("%s", anotherCupcake);`. To compare strings: `if(anotherCupcake == "yes")` --> `if (strcmp(anotherCupcake, "yes") == 0)`

Comment: As noted by others, but to be clear, C does not support comparing strings using `==`. If you write `if (anotherCupcake == "yes")` C will compare the address of `anotherCupcake` string to the address of the literal string `"yes"`. Obviously not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

try use string compare to compare values of two string. It may work.

```
if(strcmp("yes", anotherCupcake) == 0)
 {
   printf("Enter the flavor of cupcake 2: ");
   scanf("%s", &flavor2);
   printf("Enter the price of cupcake 2 $: ");
   scanf("%f", &price2);
   printf("Done! Enjoy your %s and %s cupcakes! Bye!", flavor, flavor2);
}
```